# How much financial proof do I need to show for a Schengen visa for a 14-day trip to Italy?

Tags: schengen, paperwork, italy, consulates

My wife and I are planning a 14-day trip to Italy.  How much financial proof would each one of us have to show for proof of sufficient funds for expenses as needed by Schengen visa? The calculation needs to be based on this data - 
http://www.esteri.it/mae/en/ministero/servizi/stranieri/ingressosoggiornoinitalia/mezzi_finanziari/tabella_mezzi_sussistenza.html

Amt = (22.21 + 25.82) * 15 = 720.45 Euro -> $802.40 each.

Does this sound right?

Comment: That seems low to me, and that's one of the more confusing tables I've ever seen. What cost range of hostel or hotel are you staying in? If you say $100/night (which might be low), that's $1400 there, add on food, transportation, museum entry costs...

Comment: You will have to show enough savings to pay **for the trip** and enough income/savings to **make the expense credible**.

Answer (score 1):

As always, more is always better.
I suggest a minimum of 300 per night, or at least 4k, excluding flights. Of course, don't go off spending significant portions of your income, as it would seem that it would cause suspicion. If you come from one of the visa waiver countries, you do not need to apply for a visa within a 90 day period every 180 days.
www.immihelp.com/visas/schengenvisa/means-of-substinence.html